# l How do I use the vue2 component library in vue3

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, vite

I've tried vue-demi, @vue/compat, @vue/composition-api, but I can't use vue2 components directly in vue3 + vite without modifying vue2 component library, what is the way to use it in vue3 without modifying vue2 component library dependencies?

Is there any way to use it in vue3 without modifying the vue2 component library dependencies?